# How to write a large amount of columns in a formatted file

Tags: formatting, fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to write a code in fortran90 that allows me to create lets say 20 columns (f10.6) with one space between them in to the "output file".
When I try to create file just with the 4 columns it works, but when I try to format a file with 5 or more columns it writes results wrong.

So my code for four columns looks like:

```
 do i=1, 200
     write(1,207) nq(i),plt_Dy1c4(i),plt_Dy3(i),plt_Dy4(i) 
       207   format(4(f10.6,x))
 end do
```

Similar for five columns looks like, but this doesn't works:

```
 do i=1, 200
 write(1,207) nq(i),plt_Dy1c4(i),plt_Dy3(i),plt_Dy4(i),plt_Dy5
   207   format(5(f10.6,x))
end do
```

The output files for five columns has 8200 rows instead of 200.

Is there any statement which should be used for creation of file which has many columns?

Comment: You might need to set the record length `recl` to some large value when opening the file. I need to specify this for `ifort`: `open( ..., recl=huge(1))`

Comment: The same can be achieved with an environment variable (for `ifort`): `FORT_FMT_RECL=SOMETHINGLARGE ; ./a.out`. The default is 132 bytes... For `gfortran` the variable is `GFORTRAN_DEFAULT_RECL` with a default of 1GB.

Comment: Voting to close, simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `plt_Dy5`? I have the nagging feeling that it is an array with dimension(200), as your other `plt_*` vars seem to be.

If that is the case, then for every `write()` statement, it would write out the whole 200 values of `plt_Dy5` in addition to the current index values of the other arrays, to a total of 204 values.

Since the format only allows for 5 values per row, this would mean 41 rows per write statement. Multiply this by 200 iterations of the loop, and you come to 8200 rows.

So simply replace `plt_Dy5` by `plt_D5(i)` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was my bad. 
It was mystake that I have forgot an index for the array.
It works now fine. 
Thank you very much!!!